# Linux Mint Rafaela Password

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, password

I want to boot Linux Mint Rafaela from a live USB Stick. The MD5 checksum is correct.

I am asked for a password. In the documentation I can find following: Typ as Login: "Mint" Password: -empty-

I also tried Login: "mint" Password: -empty-
I can't reach the console with strg+alt+F1 or similar combinations, so it is not possible to start Linux Mint Rafaela from a live USB Stick for me. Any suggestions?

I can't take pictures but here are the steps:

1. A screen with 3 possible choices: 
   a) Start Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit
   b) Start Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit (compatibility mode)
   c) Check the integrity of the medium
   I choose e.g. a)
2. A green Logo with Letters lm appears
3. A Screen with a random pic and a Login window appears.
   I don't want to describe the login window. It is nothing special. Just a window with first your Login and then enter and then Password, enter.
   In the right upper corner with red letters there is the message: "Incorrect username or password..."

WHO HAD THE IDEA TO ASK FOR A PASSWORD IN THE FIRST SESSION? I don't know the password!

Comment: Did you try leaving the password empty? Just hitting enter?

Comment: Yes I left the password empty. I just hit enter.

Comment: When are you asked for a password? Could you [edit] your question and include the exact steps you followed? From the first screen you saw until you are asked for a password.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I compiled a live usb with unetbootin this time instead of using dd command with bash. It was the same .iso file, but this time I dont get a Login screen. Everything works fine.